# Trying to create a new eventHandler using >> overloaded operator, lost myself trying to figure out the required syntax

Tags: c++, templates, functor

**EDIT, CLARIFICATION:**
**I want to be able to set eventHandlers using my own class EventListener using an overloaded operator `>>` and I can't figure out the syntax for it**

The problem is that the overloaded `>>=` operator will not match a parameterized eventHandler, I do not know how to declare it properly!!

OR

If I make it match, the information required to convert the generic T type to a decent useful eventHandler object is **gone**!! I need a mixed syntax for declarind a generic type T and a second generic type as it parameter .

And using the parent of eventHandler class, the efunctor is also useless as it is not parameterized.

**Example:**

**Link >> new eventHandler(&App::testFunction, app);** `/*where app is an istance of App class and testFunction is a method of App. */`

I have a class called `eventHandler` that goes under this form `eventHandler<class T>`. Now, I want to overload the `>>` operator of some class to allow me to use it like this:

```
link >> new eventHandler(&App::testFunction, App);
```

Where App is another class, and testFunction is, obviously, a method of that class. The line written abose should have as an effect a call to the `>>=` operator of the link's class (called, conveniently,`Link`).

I will post part of my code to make it more clearly:

```
class Link
{
public:
    eventListener* EventListener;
    Link()
    {
        this->EventListener = new eventListener();
    }   

    // PROBLEM
    // I am lost here, tried different syntaxes but with no success
    //template<template<class G> class T, class F> 

    template <class T>
    Link operator>>=(T& ev)
    { 
        cout << "something";
         // Here there is no way to declare the proper eventHandler
        eventHandler<?>* event = (eventHandler<?>)ev;
         // I need something like T<F> 
        event->eventName = 'onTest';
        this->eventListener->add(event);
        return *this; 
} 

};

template<class T, class F> 
T operator>>(T& lhs, F& rhs)
{ 
    return T(lhs)>>=rhs;
} 

class App
{
public:
    void testFunction(e evt)
    {
        cout << "it works!" << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    App* app = new App;
    Link* link = new link;
    Link link1;

    eventHandler<App>* ev = new eventHandler<App>(app, &App::testFunction);
    link1 >> ev;    

    // this line should echo "it works!"
    link1.EventListener->triggerEvent("onTest");

    // PART 2
    // HOW CAN I USE?
    // link >> ev; 
    // when link is a Link*

    return 0;
}
```

MY question is about how to declare the method `operator>>=` from Link so that automatically will enable me that kind of functionality.

Clarifications:
- I want to be able to add to the EventListener class a new eventHandler using the `>>` operator on the Link class having as right hand operand an actual eventHandler;

EDIT 1:

And I have a second question:
How to declare the `>>` overloaded function so that I will be called with pointer to the Link class... meaning what can I do if I want to use `link` with `>>` instead of `link1`.

**Answer to PART2:** My guess is that I just have to dereference the pointer in order to use the operator overloading.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

This is a version of the code that might explain it a little better. My problem is where the compiler fails, at matching `>>=` operator inside Link class, from there if that is solved properly it might work, the problem is that I cannot find how to match it and keep the event signature.

And now, I better let the code speak for itself:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "events/events.h"
using namespace std;

class Link
{
public:
    eventListener* EventListener;

public:
    Link()
    {
        this->EventListener = new eventListener();
    }   

    template<class T>
    Link operator>>=(const T& ev)
    { 
        ev->eventName = "onReceive";
        this->EventListener->add(ev);
        return *this; 
    }
};

template<class T, class F> 
T operator>>(T& lhs, const F& rhs)
{ 
    return T(lhs)<<=rhs;
} 

class App
{
public:
    void testReceive(e evt)
    {
        cout << "it works" << "\n" << evt.value;
    }

};

class demo
{
public:
    Link* parent;
    void testit(char* msg)
    {
        parent->EventListener->triggerEvent("onReceive", this, msg);
    }
};

int main()
{
    App* app = new App;
    Link link;

    eventHandler<App>* ev = new eventHandler<App>(app, &App::testReceive);
    link >> ev; 

    demo d;
    d.parent = &link;
    // should output "it works!"
    d.testit("here");

    return 0;
}
```

I will also post my events definitions:

```
#ifndef EVENTS_H
#define EVENTS_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "clist.h"
#include <string>

enum scope {global = 0, scoped};

struct e
{
    void* target;
    void* value;
};

class efunctor //abstract
{
public:
    std::string eventname;
    virtual void operator()(e evt)
    { }

    virtual void Call(e evt)
    { }

};

template <class T>
class eventHandler : public efunctor
{
private:
    T* scope;
    void (T::*eventMethod)(e);
public:
    std::string name;
    std::string eventname;
    eventHandler(std::string eventnam, T* objscope,  void(T::*func)(e)) 
    { 
        this->scope = objscope;
        this->eventMethod = func;
        this->eventname = eventnam;
    }

    eventHandler(T* objscope,  void(T::*func)(e)) 
    { 
        this->scope = objscope;
        this->eventMethod = func;
    }

    eventHandler(void(T::*func)(e)) 
    {
        this->eventMethod = func;
    }

    void operator()(e evt)
    {
        (scope->*eventMethod)(evt);
    }          

    void Call(e evt)
    { 
        (scope->*eventMethod)(evt);
    }
};

class eventListener
{
private:
    clist< clist<efunctor* > > methods;
public:

    template <class T>
    void add(T other)
    {
        other->name = ToString(this->methods[other->eventname].length());
        methods[other->eventname][methods[other->eventname].length()] = other;
    }

    template <class T>
    void remove(T other)
    {
        methods[other->eventname]->remove(other->name);
    }

    template <class F>
    void triggerEvent(std::string name, void* target, F result)
    {
        e evt;
        evt.target = target;
        evt.value = (char*)result;
        for(methods[name].iterateStart(); 
                    !methods[name].eoi(); 
                    methods[name].next())
        {
            (*(methods[name].getCurrentIteration()))(evt);
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

Comment: There is an awful lot of `new` and not very much RAII or `delete` in your code.

Comment: Well, I want to see it working first and then take care of that.

Comment: Still please don't write (or share) code like that, it sets a bad precedent. Furthermore I have a really hard time figuring out what exactly your problem is, so you might want to clarify.

Comment: Just a quick one: `link >> ev` won't ever call an overloaded shift operator. However, you can use `*link >> ev` if you have an overloaded shift operator for `Link`.

Comment: Also, you shift operator almost certainly should take a non-const reference as first parameter: adding an event is changing the object, both in a logical way as well as in a practical way. Adding an event to a const object is lying about the constness.

Comment: Made the change about the const. But still no solution about how to get the information about any eventHandler to the `>>=` overload inside the Link class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the excessive use of `new` there are other things which I think you need to get conceptually clear before trying something like this. There isn't really any problem in overloading `operator>>()` to call a suitable member version of `operator>>=()` if necessary although it might not even necessary to do this: if you control the left hand argument of your shift operator, you can make this a member if you want to. It just doesn't work with `std::istream` this way because you can't control the standard C++ library class [template].

Before going any further, let's answer the question you added first: you cannot overload any operator which involves only built-in types. Pointers are considered built-in types. End of story. You should be using pointers anyway: they are a low-level abstraction you need in some place but on a higher level you want to deal with objects of appropriate classes. This doesn't make things harder in any way but it makes things easier.

In your code all of a sudden some template template shows up: this is almost certainly not necessary and rather part of your problem. Also, if you want your events receiver to be in some sort polymorphic, you will need a small inheritance hierarchy somewhere: you would define a base class which exposes the interface use to trigger an event and a templated derived class which implements the few virtual functions defined by this interface. When an event is invoked the base just calls the virtual function and the even receives it. This is how `std::function<Signature>` effectively works.

I think there are too many undefined things in your question to answer it with a code example which effectively implements what you want. Personally, I would follow the model of `std::function<>` and define an event template which take the signatures of events to be triggered as argument and function object with the corresponding signature as receivers. That is, the event you subscribe to looks like this:

```
event<void(std::string)> onTest;
```

If you want to add an object with a specific member to be called on it you would do something and this is a common use case, you can create an `EventHandler` class template to be used with this which effectively does something along the lines of

```
onTest >> std::bind(std::mem_fn(&App::testFunction), std::ref(app), _1);
```

(this just uses `std::bind()` for brevity; if you want to support function with a fixed number of arguments this is easily implemented, assuming you cannot use `std::bind()` or `boost::bind()` although you don't want to reimplement `bind()`: this is a fairly hairy thing to do).

Here is a complete and working example which I think shows all the ingredients (and gets as close as what I think you actually want as possible):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct event_base
{
    virtual ~event_base() {}
    virtual void call(std::string const&) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct event: event_base
{
    event(T* o, void (T::*m)(std::string const&)):
        object(o),
        member(m)
    {
    }

private:
    void call(std::string const& arg) {
        (this->object->*member)(arg);
    }
    T*   object;
    void (T::*member)(std::string const&);
};


template <typename T>
event_base* make_event(T* object, void (T::*member)(std::string const&)) {
    return new event<T>(object, member);
}

class event_listener
{
public:
    ~event_listener() { std::for_each(events.begin(), events.end(), &deleter); }
    void add(event_base* event) { this->events.push_back(event); }
    void trigger(std::string const& argument) const {
        for (std::vector<event_base*>::const_iterator it(events.begin()), end(events.end());
             it != end; ++it) {
            (*it)->call(argument);
        }
    }

private:
    static void deleter(event_base* ptr) { delete ptr; }
    std::vector<event_base*> events;
};

class Link
{
public:
    event_listener listener;
    void operator>>= (event_base* ev) { this->listener.add(ev); }
};

void operator<< (Link& link, event_base* ev) {
    link >>= ev;
}

class App
{
public:
    void onTest(std::string const& arg) { std::cout << "App::onTest(" << arg << ")\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::auto_ptr<Link> link(new Link);
    std::auto_ptr<App>  app(new App);

    *link << make_event(app.get(), &App::onTest);
    link->listener.trigger("hello event");
}
```

Note, that there are obvious extensions like making the argument type a template argument. This amounts to just adding this template argument in various places but the overall approach stays the same.

Comment: Actually my problem is that the operator >>= doesn't match my calls as eventHandler is a class template, and will not reach the function call. So I needed the syntax to define that operator overloading to match any eventHandler with any parameter, also eventHandler is an inheritance of an efunctor class, but that doesn't help me either.

Comment: Based on the code example you gave, your problem is that you haven't put all the details together. It may be true that you perceive this to be related to the `eventHandler` being a class template but the actual problem is that you will need two things: 1. you need to know how your events are called, i.e. the arguments to the event need to be decided before you register any function; 2. you need some form of type erasure to hold the objects of different types. There is no build-in syntax to do it at once, you need to build it up, e.g. using an approach like `std::function<...>`

Comment: I know how my events are called, they are stocked in a list, under an event name, as "onTest" and when the method triggerEvent on eventListener is called with the parameter "onTest" all function that are there are called. I made the class myself, and now I'm stuck on trying to make up a syntax good enough to handle my requests.

Comment: As I said before: I don't think you know, yet, what it takes! You **need** some level type erasure. On possibility is to give your `eventHandler<App, ...>` type a suitable base class and add the type of the signature you are using to define that. Obviously, this would be painful to write, i.e. you could create a factory function creating your actual even handler. Once you got this far, you are essentially there. I'll add code doing this to my reply shortly...

Comment: Please check my edits on top of the question. Is hard to explain what I actually want, consider that I have a base class efunctor from which eventHandler is inherited. Now getting the parameters to match the definition of `>>=` operator and to get all the information up there might be a pain, but still there has to be a way... isn't there any way to define a proper template method for that??

Comment: I have already done that, my event_base is called efunctor, I am using this technique for the parameter of my list, that is also a template class, but still, my eventHandler has some other properties than an efunctor, and when I try to access them, it will fail, I am  no trying again to inspire from your example, this is exactly why I needed a template definition, so that I might use all of eventHandler signature, and also allow any class to implement `>>=` overload, on any type of eventHandler, you function make_event is similar to my `new eventHandler`.

Comment: I have added my source for the event, it is exactly as you proposed by it still fail to match. The problems are obvious. The eventHandler have different structure than its base class, so even if it is a pointer to it, it won't match the target eventhandler. Maybe I should change it so that it will match. Still youra doesn't match either, what am I missing??

Comment: I managed to make it work, but with great sacrifices, thank you for your help. It was exactly as you said, but still I seek for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you will need to make your `eventHandler<T>` derive from a class like `eventHandlerBase` so you can refer to any `eventHandler<T>` of any type `T` by having a pointer to `eventHandlerBase`... i.e. `Link::EventListener` delcared as type `eventHandlerBase *`.

Then something like this might work:

```
template<typename T>
const link &operator>>=(const eventHandler<T>& ev)
{ 
    ev->eventName = "onTest";
    this->EventListener = &ev;
}
```

(and without the `new` statement for `Link::EventListener` within `Link()`.)

Comment: In your example, it won't match the `>>=` operator as the `>>` operator is parameterized and do not match the candidate.